# Как сделать кастомные bullets в swiper.js слайдере?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, swiper

Здраствуйте, столкнулся с буллетами как на скрине. Как их можно сделать имея swiper.js?[image: Буллеты на слайдере]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите `pagination` для вашего слайдера:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'bullets',
  },
});
```

[Документация Swiper - настройка Pagination](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#pagination)

Comment: Я хотел узнать как сделать именно такую же пагинацию как и на скрине, вот с этой зеленой полосочкой, чтобы при перелистывании слайдера она меняла свою форму уменьшаясь в длине до размеров самой точки когда она находится ровно между слайдами и после перетекала на соседнюю.

Comment: @АндрейГордеев берете селектор CSS 'swiper-pagination-current' (активный индекс), и указываете длину, ширину, цвет фона (зеленый), стоит лишь открыть ссылку, там написано с чем вам работать. С анимацией вы тоже разберетесь, можно прописать css для стандартной кнопки, css для активной, добавить `transition` с длительностью и типом анимации.